# What are the recommended regular expressions for tezos wallet and contract addresses?

Tags: wallets, contract, address, validation

I need to validate Tezos addresses and have arrived at the following prefixed base 58 regular expressions for wallet and contract addresses.

Contract:

```
/KT1[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{33}/
```

Wallet:

```
/tz[1-3][1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{33}/
```

Are these regexes sufficient, or could something like a `KT2` or `tz4` address ever be introduced into the protocol?

Answer (score 4):

Transaction rollups coming with the `Jakarta` protocol will introduce new addresses with prefixes (`txr1`, `tz4`, and `txi`). And the `K` protocol will also introduce a new ones `scr1`, etc.

You can find all the prefixes here: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/lib_crypto/base58.ml#L348
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/tx_rollup_prefixes.ml#L33

Also, something to have in mind is that the regex is not enough to validate the address. It uses `base58check` encoding, which includes a checksum at the end of the address.

Comment: very informative, thank you. would any of these other adresses ever be able to hold FA12 or FA2 tokens in a way that is user controllable? it seems like the `tz4` layer 2 address would be a candidate for this, will they be indistinguishable for the tz1,tz2,tz3 layer 1 addresses when they eventually interact with existing contracts?

Comment: They are distinguishable, `tz4` will have a new type `tx_rollup_l2_address`.